# What is the Catholic exegetical warrant behind the 2 interpretations of "perfect" in Matt 5:48 and Matt 19:21?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, words-of-jesus, evangelical-counsel

In Matthew there are 2 instances where Jesus said "to be perfect" (both rendering the Greek word τέλειοι).

1. [Matt 5:48](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5%3A43-48&version=DRA): Sermon on the Mount about loving our enemies, directed to the whole audience:

   > "Be you therefore **perfect**, as also your heavenly Father is perfect."
2. [Matt 19:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+19%3A16-30&version=DRA): Jesus replying the rich man who asked Him how to get everlasting life:

   > "Jesus saith to him: If thou wilt be **perfect**, go sell what thou hast, and give to the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come follow me."

In my understanding of the Catholic tradition, the 1st one is a "precept" (binding for every Catholic) but the 2nd one is a "counsel", only for those called to a religious life taking the vows of povery, chastity, and obedience.  (See the Catholic Encyclopedia article [Evangelical Counsels](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04435a.htm)).

While I understand the logic behind the teaching (which I happen to agree personally), **what is the exegetical warrant for the two different interpretations & applications of the same word?** Isn't perfect supposed to be the same for everyone?

Possibly relevant: [Protestant's objections to the "two-tiered system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_counsels#Criticisms_of_supererogatory_interpretation_of_evangelical_counsels).

Comment: The perfection spoken of in the fifth chapter does indeed *overlap* with the one mentioned in the nineteenth (5:40-42), but it is not *identically* equal. We find similar crescendos in other passages, such as Matthew 19:8-12 and 1 Corinthians 7:1-2, 7:7-9.